# How to access image of an Iframe using javaScript / jQuery / Angular

Tags: iframe

I want to access the image which is in Iframe using javascript / jQuery / AngularJS.
I tried with

```
window.frames['myIFrame'].contentDocument
```

but it did not work for me.

Comment: Can you add a sample HTML page (either minimal or link to one) so that someone can base and explain an approach on it?